# How can I prevent Sitecore content from being accessed under any language identifer?

Tags: sitecore

How do you remove the ability to find content under language identifiers in Sitecore?

Content here:

```
/about
```

Is also available at:

```
/en/about
```

Weirder yet, any attempt to find content under a *different* language identifier results in an error about not being able to find Views.

```
/es/about
/pt-br/about
/aa/about  (this is invented..)
```

I don't want content available under *any* language identifier -- the URLs above should simply be 404s.

I can't find where this language identifier is isolated and processed.  I removed the `LanguageResolver` from the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline, but this didn't change the behavior.

There are many blog posts about turning off language embedding in the `LinkManager`, which I've done, but that's not enough -- I do not want content being produced under any language code. The firs segment of the URL should be treated like any other segment. Requests for `/en/[whatever]` should 404.

Comment: Why would you want to prevent people from finding pages on your site (as you would with a 404)? Maybe a redirect is a better solution.. What is the reason for blocking those urls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As well as setting the LinkManager to never embed, you also need to set the `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` setting to `false`.

Source: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2015/03/prevent-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms-from-interpreting-url-path-prefixes-as-language-names.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a custom 404 resolver in place, you just need to change the Sitecore setting `Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage` from `true` to `false` like so:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <settings>
      <setting name="Languages.AlwaysStripLanguage" value="false" /> 
    </settings>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```